# Destructor of member variable called in constructor - compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio 2012.  First the SSCCE:

```
class CacheImpl
{
public:
    float* m_cache;

    CacheImpl()
    {
        m_cache=(float*)new float[1];
    }

    ~CacheImpl()
    {        
        delete [] m_cache;
    }
};

class Image 
{
public:
    Image() {}
    ~Image() {}
};

static const Image g_tmpImg;

class Filter
{       

public:

    Filter() : m_img(Image())
    //Filter() : m_img(g_tmpImg) // <-- This variant works
    {
        //Empty
    }

private:

    CacheImpl m_cache;
    const Image &m_img;
};

int main()
{
    Filter f;
    return 0;
}
```

When running this (compiled in debug mode) I get a CRT assert on the delete in CacheImpl, and looking at the assembly listing of Filter() or setting a breakpoint in ~CacheImpl() shows that ~CacheImpl() is being called at the end of the Filter constructor for no apparent reason (and indeed, this doesn't happen in VS2010).  Instead ~Image() is being called for the temporary object, which VS2012 *does not* do.

When compiling this in VS2012 I get the warning "C4413: 'Filter::m_img' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits".  This I understand, but I expect a dangling reference, not a crash because the wrong object is being destructed.  Have I stumbled upon a compiler bug or should I just accept this as undefined behavior and not initialize references to temporaries?  For context, in my real code the dangling reference is never used when Filter is created with such a constructor.

Comment: [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html): use `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, but that's not really the point.  The allocation of memory is just there to expose the double destruction.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Still doesn't have anything to do with the actual question. But thanks for this nice catchphrase, haven't heard it before.

Comment: As a side not: The C-Cast is not necessary. `m_cache=(float*)new float[1];` Nor a good idea in any C++ code.

Comment: Indeed. The allocation used _aligned_malloc initially, but I changed it to make the example smaller (no include file necessary).

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug. I would report it. Note that reversing the order of the members fixes the problem.

Comment: Reversing the order removes the double destruction.  However, looking at the assembly or adding printouts to constructors and destructors reveals that the temporary Image object is not destructed at all (which is the case for the original ordering of members as well).

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that this is a compiler bug - but "undefined behaviour" essentially means "anything goes" and you storing the reference to an object soon to be destructed qualifies as undefined behaviour. So you should just accept this and stop initializing references with temporaries.

Comment: As far as I know, binding a temporary to a reference is _not_ undefined behaviour (see 12.2/5 bullet 1). Using a dangling reference is, though (= using an object whose lifetime has ended).

Comment: @DyP That's what I'd have thought too.  As I never use the reference in this state, my gut feeling is that the example should be well-defined.